# How to Run Nested For Loop (for Fixed turn) in Django?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

Hello I have to make something like this

```
<div class='grid'>    
   <div class='width-one-third'>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
   </div>
   <div class='width-one-third'>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
   </div>
   <div class='width-one-third'>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here All those items on is from a table. So Here I need to run First loop for total items and each nested for 2 time. How can I in Django template?

This shoes me nested loop is possible: [Nested loop in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232320/nested-loop-in-django-template)

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I Tried By passing a binding of

{'n' : range(n) }
to the template, then

{% for i in n %}
  <div class="width-one-third">
    <ol>
      {% for blogs in blogs %}
      <li>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ol>
  </div>
  {% endfor %} But no worked it Run the same post again and again

Comment: Good. I hope that you had found your solution by explaining what you have tried

Comment: It did not solve my exact Problem. And The Problem was In e very <li> I need to get the Items from one table. Through The above Code I get the same <li> items on Every Inner Div. Is there any way to solve this?